# What are the available variable assignments and expand methods that can be used in Makefile files?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to parse some Makefile files to read some configs them them and I encountered a wide range of expressions like:

```
AAA := Some, text
BBB_NAME := @AAA@ (c)
CCC = value
DDD = Some other $(CCC) xxx
```

I would like to know if all of these are valid and what if there is any difference between them (so I can properly parse them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all valid, as you can tell by putting them in a Makefile and running it. If you want to know what values they actually take, you can try

```
$(info $(AAA))
```

(Note that the only real problem is with the `(c)` in `BBB_NAME`, it can cause problems if you pass it into other functions.)

The one tricky part is the difference between `=` and `:=` (and other assignment operators). Full details are in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles), but basically `:=` evaluates the right-hand side at once, while `=` holds off until the left-hand side is evaluated somewhere. Consider

```
CCC = value
DDD := Some other $(CCC) xxx
EEE = Some other $(CCC) xxx
```

The value of `DDD` is now `Some other value xxx`, while the value of EEE is `Some other $(CCC) xxx`. If you use them somewhere:

```
$(info $(DDD))
$(info $(EEE))
```

Make expands `$(DDD)` and `$(EEE)` to the same thing and you see

```
Some other value xxx
Some other value xxx
```

But there are differences:

```
CCC = value
DDD := Some other $(CCC) xxx
EEE = Some other $(CCC) xxx

DDD := $(DDD) and yyy   # This is perfectly legal.
EEE := $(EEE) and yyy   # Infinite recursion. Make will not allow this.

CCC = dimension

$(info $(DDD))          # Produces "Some other value xxx and yyy"
$(info $(EEE))          # Produces "Some other dimension xxx"
```

Comment: It's more accurate to use the $(value ...) function, as in `$(info $(value AAA))`.  This will show the content of the `AAA` variable WITHOUT trying to expand it first.  Using a reference like `$(AAA)` will expand the value before displaying it.